# How to insert or use the PackageTemplate?

Tags: front-end

In the system resource file `MiscStrings.tr` there is a template:

```
@@resource PackageTemplate
Notebook[{
Cell[BoxData[
    RowBox[{"BeginPackage", "[", "\"\<\[Placeholder]`\>\"", "]"}]], "Code"],
Cell[BoxData[
    RowBox[{"Begin", "[", "\"\<`Private`\>\"", "]"}]], "Code"],
Cell[BoxData[
    RowBox[{"End", "[", "]"}]], "Code"],
Cell[BoxData[
    RowBox[{"EndPackage", "[", "]"}]], "Code"]
}]
```

I suppose there is also an automatic way to insert or use this template.  What is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the template using `FrontEndResource`:

```
 FrontEndResource["PackageTemplate"]
 (* Notebook[
  {Cell[BoxData[RowBox[{"BeginPackage", "[", "\"\[Placeholder]`\"", "]"}]], "Code"], 
   Cell[BoxData[RowBox[{"Begin", "[", "\"`Private`\"", "]"}]], "Code"],
   Cell[BoxData[RowBox[{"End", "[", "]"}]], "Code"], 
   Cell[BoxData[RowBox[{"EndPackage", "[", "]"}]], "Code"]}] *)
```

Usage example:

```
NotebookPut[FrontEndResource["PackageTemplate"]]
```

[image]

Comment: I *thought* I must be missing something; thanks.  Is `FrontEndResource` documented somewhere?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I have not come across anything in the docs; but, as you must have noticed, text resource files have several example uses such as the piece ``FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`NotebookPut[FEPrivate`FrontEndResource["FEExpressions", "SlideshowTemplate"]]]`` in `MenuSetup.tr`. Finding the right syntax took several "trial-and-crash" attempts.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard This is not your first encounter with `FrontEndResource`. See your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6149495/615464).

Comment: @Sjoerd More evidence of my failing memory. ::sigh::